# Bash tab completion using environment variables without expanding

Tags: bash, environment-variables

I would like to be able to do this:

```
cd $HOME/../[TAB]
```

And get this (where `$HOME` remains intact as a variable name):

```
cd $HOME/../username/
```

But instead the variable is expanded:

```
cd /home/username/../username/
```

This would be particularly useful to me when searching through the history. Is there some option that can enable this behavior or would it require rewriting parts of the `bash_completion` script?

Answer (score 1):

This would require modifying `bash_completion` functions. The behaviour seems to be an effect of the functions expanding the words for completion. If you run bash without the completion scripts loaded, for example using `bash --norc`, you'll see the behaviour is what you want.

With zsh, on the other hand, completion offers both:

```
~ echo $HOME/../
$HOME/../       /home/muru/../
```

For the particular case of `$HOME`, you might want to use `~` instead, which isn't expanded for me.